# Unobserved task exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Getting this exception for many times,
what does this mean?

Comment: It means you're firing off async tasks without waiting for their completion.